# How to automatically adjust a datatable based on the browsers zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am wondering if there is a simple way to allow a JQuery datatable to re-size itself while the user is using a browsers zoom-in, zoom-out features. Currently When I zoom in and out on my data table the data either shrinks or grows too large for the table. And I also noticed that  after I zoom out or in I can refresh the page and the datatable resizes itself to how it should look. Any insight or possible redirection to a question where this has been answered (could not find one) would be appreciated. Thanks.

#### Here are my JavaScript table properties:

```
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "aaSorting": [[4, "desc"], [5, "asc"]],
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sScrollY": "35em",
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can tie a datables redraw event to a window re-size function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    oTable.fnDraw(false)        
});
```

This assumes you initialized your table with the variable oTable like this:

```
var oTable = $("#tableName").dataTable({
"bJQueryUI": true,
"bStateSave": true,
"iDisplayLength": 50,
"aaSorting": [[4, "desc"], [5, "asc"]],
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"sScrollY": "35em",
"sScrollX": "100%",
"bScrollCollapse": true
});
```

Comment: Valuable information for anyone looking to do this in the future, regardless of if OP ends up using it. +1

Comment: Exactly what I needed only instead of "window" I applied the "ID-tag" of the container I wanted to adjust my datatable to. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that if you do server side processing, this might cripple your backend with requests. I suggest that you do some kind of `setTimeout(...)` delay system so that if the resize event gets fired for example 15 times per second, the `fnDraw(...)` would still be called only once.

Answer (score 2):

You could also set the table in question to have `style="width:100%;"` and then use the `"bAutoWidth":false` option for DataTables. It then maintains your width and you don't actually need a redraw. Especially for tables doing complex Server side processing tables, this is quite a bit lighter. For the HTML just change the style

```
<table id="tableName" style="width:100%;">...</table>
```

And then your DataTables add the option:

```
var oTable = $("#tableName").dataTable({
    // Your other options here...
    "bAutoWidth":false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-draw table when window resizes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Load datatable here

   $(window).bind('resize', function () {
      table.draw();
   });
});
```